# Variadic function process arguments in reverse order. why?

Tags: c, printf, variadic

I've crafted a small code to process a variable number of strings, but some how I got these strings processed in reverse order.
The expected output is: Jolasd14; actual output is: asdJol14.

```
int Columna(int anchoColumna,...){
    va_list longitudCadena;
    va_start ( longitudCadena, anchoColumna );
    char caracter;
    do{
        caracter =va_arg ( longitudCadena, int );
        anchoColumna -= ( int ) caracter;
    } while ( caracter != '\0' );
    va_end ( longitudCadena );
    return anchoColumna;
}
int main ( int cantidadArgumentos, char** argumentos ) {
    printf("%d",Columna(20,printf("Jol"),printf("asd")));
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
I tried a similar thing with strings only and I got the expected output.

[image: ExpectedOutput]

Comment: The premise of your question is wrong. It's any function call that can do this as the order of function argument evaluation is unspecified in C.

Answer (score 3):

The order that `printf("Jol")` and `printf("asd")` execute is not specified.  They both occur before `Columna()` is executed.

Simply executed them is the order you want before the `Columna()` call, passing in their respective return values.

```
int a = printf("Jol");
int b = printf("asd");
printf("%d",Columna(20,a,b);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however i tried a similar approach with strings only and I got the expected output